# mod_rewrite how to transfer root to specific file

Tags: mod-rewrite

i am using smarty framework and the urls are dynamic build with master-layout index file.
i want to make a mod_rewrite rule to transfer the url
www.mysite.com to /mysiteSubfolder/member/index.php
No redirect, just to map the urls to those calls, for the sake of SEO friendly url.

www.mysite.com/home.html works as desired but the root url not working.
i tried the following but it just stays on root url's index file root/index.php

here is my current .htacces code

```
Options -Multiviews
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$        /mysiteSubfolder/client/index.php (not working)
RewriteRule ^home.html$   /mysiteSubfolder/client/index.php (working)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your root .htaccess, ie, /.htaccess, but not in /mysiteSubfolder/client/.htaccess,  should be like this (TESTED on Debian/Apache2):

```
Options -Multiviews
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$        /mysiteSubfolder/client/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^home.html$   /mysiteSubfolder/client/index.php [L]
```

Comment: hi thanks for reply, will test when get home. What does the [L] does?

Comment: [L]: flag indicating the Last rule to be executed.

Comment: ok that helped but now i get "No input file specified" on godaddy, my other link which is following is not working: RewriteRule ^vendors.html    /mysiteSubfolder/client/index.php/part_general/sect_allvendors/ [L] i tried this: cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1 in php5.ini but didn't worked

Comment: /mysiteSubfolder/client/index.php must exists really and physically?

Comment: this part: /mysiteSubfolder/client/index.php exist, and /part_general/sect_allvendors/ are queryString values. this works onmy other hosting but not in godaddy

Comment: hi i changed my hosting from godaddy to hostgator, now i don't receive "No input file specified" error but now the rules dont refelect any changes, when open home.html it works but on any other page it gets back to home page. any idea plz?

Comment: Have you the same /.htaccess?

Comment: yes i have same .htaccess, which is working fine on my other domain. i have tested and i think its ignoring the values //part_general/sect_allvendors/ after index.php in  /mysiteSubfolder/client/index.php/part_general/sect_allvendors/ but when i directly enter  /mysiteSubfolder/client/index.php/part_general/sect_allvendors/ it works, but not with rewrite rule plz help i'm very upset and tired

Comment: Put slashes after index.php might complicate your requests.

Comment: this is my current rule i have / after index.php, do i have to chnage something? RewriteRule vendors.html$ /subfolder/client/index.php/part_general/sect_allvendors/?test=test

Comment: part_general/sect_allvendors/ is file path or URL parameters? if they are, they shall be passed after '?' as url args...

Comment: they are actually URL parameters, query string like, my index file includes the page  /client/allvendors.php using those parameter, but if i send them as regular query string with ?part=general&sect=allvendors it breaks my website. one links contains RewriteRule ^cart.html$ /subfolder/client/index.php/part_general/sect_cart/ and in page i have a link cart.html?act=add&id=1 this link breaks if i do ? after index bcoz it becomes, /subfolder/client/index.php?part=general&sect=cart?act=add&id=1 besides it is working fine in other hosting why issue in here?

Comment: You hosting server may have already some rewriterules, as we don't know them, it's not easy to do.

Comment: :( so i must contact the hosting? its very frustrating and payed godaddy in full payment for year and they don't even answer back. now used hostgator and they have similar problem. i'm dooomed

Comment: This shall be the first step... It's eaier with ourself server from A to Z.

Comment: i'll try to contact them. i hope they can help. i had talk before bying hostgator hosting about this issue, but they said they are not technically trained to handle mod_rewrite specific issues, but they will try to assist as much possible. so maybe i'm gona regret something.

Comment: i'm on shared hosting, so i guess i wont have access to those settings. and i don't even know what to do even i get those. thanks 4 ur time, i hope i get some solution, bcoz changing the applications architecture will be big mess and client don't have time. and the application was just administered by me old developer is not here anymore so i don't know what and how he did.

Comment: ok the hosting support is not able to solve the issue. now i have only one option change the rewrite rules. i am only facing problem with this rule: RewriteRule ^subfolder/cart.html$  /exam-zone/client/index.php?part=general&sect=cart i have a link which have a query string cart.html?act=add_product&id=1 now how to get values after ? and append them with previous rule.

Comment: i have made a new question for this if you can plz chk that and reply there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960956/mod-rewrite-how-to-append-querystring-values-after-in-rewrite-statement